# php quotation strip

Tags: php, quotes, strip

In my webpage, I want the website to greet the user, but the username is surrounded by 'single quotations'. Since this isn't to prevent MySQL injection, i just want to remove quotes around my name on the display page.

Ex: Welcome 'user'!
I'm trying to find the way where i can strip the quotations around the user and have it display on the example below.

Ex: Welcome user!

The only line of code that I can think relating is this:

$login = $_SESSION['login'];

Does anyone know how to strip single lines quotes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're sure that the first and last characters of `$login` are always a `'` you can use [`substr()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to do something like

```
$login = substr($_SESSION['login'], 1, -1); // example 1
```

You can strip all `'` from the string with [`str_replace()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$login = str_replace("'", '', $_SESSION['login']); // example 2
```

Or you can use the [`trim()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function, which is in fact the same as example 1:

```
$login = trim($_SESSION['login'], "'"); // example 3
```

My personal favorite is example 3, because it can easily be extended to strip away both quote types:

```
$login = trim($_SESSION['login'], "'\""); // example 4
```

Comment: is substr() method the fastest when it comes to performance??

Comment: @Xitcod13: How often do you expect that code to run? If you're not talking about several thousand calls: don't worry!

Comment: Keeping the biennial commenting going: @ Xitcod13: substr: 3.1371190547943s, str_replace: 4.3370628356934s, trim: 2.6876559257507s. Trimmed a string $strwithquotes="'this is the login string'" 10000000 times with each function above :) - PHP 5.4.24 (cli) (built: Jan 19 2014 21:32:15)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to use the trim() function. It usually trims whitespace characters, but you may pass it a string containing characters you want to be removed:

```
echo 'Welcome ' . trim($login, "'");
```

See http://php.net/trim